# Is it possible to create a graphical designer for a specific domain?

Tags: designer

I'm currently on the project where we are developing a designer that our developers and customers should use to create / modify our web pages.

I like the project a lot because of the challenges, plus I have an opportunity to learn other technologies.  However, I don't believe in its success.  I truly believe that it's going to be to inflexible for our developers and to complex for our customers.

Do you know any company or individual who was successfull with [Graphical DSL](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/25/Graphical-Domain-Specific-Languages.aspx)?
Microsoft created designers in Visual Studio, BizTalk, SQL but I don't know anyone who would use only these designers to create an application without typing a source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple years ago, we created a pretty advanced WYSIWYG graphical designer specifically for putting together Coupon Books.  It was a database application with the graphical capabilities built in.

It output production grade files that were sent directly to press.

The cool part?  100% web based.  We used PHP, MySQL, and ImageMagick to power the backend.

So, sure, it is possible.

Comment: I'm afraid that what we are trying to create a little bit more complex.  However, your reply made me more optimistic. +1

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/). With it, you can draw images, and it can output to SVG; which is just XML, so you can use that, then, to generate code.

-- Edit

Though re-reading, you don't appear to be asking how, but why, or if it's possible in general. If so, disregard me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it is possible. Microsoft has done this for windows forms :)

I believe your question is really is it cost-effective to do so. The answer is probably dependent on the level of user-friendliness, integration, etc. To do something like the designers for Microsoft forms probably costs millions. But, for a less-integrated but probably useful tool, a solution such as suggested by silky would probably be possible and cost-effective.

Comment: May be I'm wrong but I've never seen that someone creates production Windows form application with designer only (no source code typing).

Comment: From what I understand, there is going to be code-behind for your application as well - but you are only going to expose editing of the user interface elements via the designer.

Producing a code-less GUI tool would undoubtedly end up creating a TURING-complete set of visual objects so that programming is done via visual objects. Windows Biztalk server is an example of this - they have flowcharted workflows that include control constructs equivalent in power to loops and if-then-else, so combined with the IO from the workflow it is turing complete.